# How to get value of variables in yocto recipes

Tags: open-source, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I want to get value of variables in yocto recipes with overrides resolving.

## Background

I'm developing a custom yocto runtime image at work.
Recently, my colleagues want me to export some values of variables.

I thought I can do that by `bitbake -e` or `bitbake-getvar`, but I found that this command sometimes doesn't return actual value of the variable.

For example, when I get RDEPENDS of vim package, the result is as follows.
(Please note that RDEPENDS is just an example, and I also need to extract some other variables. )

```
$ bitbake-getvar -r vim RDEPENDS
none
```

## Question

I understand that if I want to retrieve RDEPENDS variables, I need to do the following

```
$ bitbake-getvar -r gcc --value RDEPENDS
$ bitbake-getvar -r gcc --value RDEPENDS:gcc
```

- Are there any other overrides that need to be considered to get RDEPENDS?
- If I want to get the value of a variable other than RDEPENDS, should I also get the two patterns above?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If I understand your question correct - I think what you need is a good `regex` with `bitbake -e`

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But I think I can't resolve this because some overrides are acutually activated, but others are not and bitbake -e commands doesn't distinguish between activated variables from inactivated variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple levels of override, some are applied in the bitbake -e output but task specific overrides and package specific overrides would not be.

A single recipe can generate multiple different packages. The packages generated are roughly those listed in PACKAGES. You could therefore iterate over PACKAGES and obtain each RDEPENDS variable for each package.

Similarly, a recipe can have multiple different tasks so it wouldn't make sense to expose those with bitbake -e.

Bitbake does have an API called tinfoil and bitbake-getvar uses this to obtain values. You can set overrides and then query values using that API which is effectively what the packaging code does to read these values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel like the package-specific override should be resolved since bitbake-getvar specifies the package name, but the task-specific override is out of the control.

Comment: You specify the recipe name to getvar, not the package name. One recipe can have multiple different packages.